# is it possible "transfer" a running application to another terminal/user?

Tags: linux, terminal, transparency, transfer

All,

I sshed to a linux server then run an appliction in termial on my PC, but my PC needs to reboot by some reason. And by now the application still in running status.

May I know is it possible to open another terminal by ssh on another PC then "transparency transfer" the running application to the new opened terminal?  Thanks!

And I know the `nohup cmd &` , but it may not suit for my case.

Thanks for any hint.

B. Rgs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give [**tmux**](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) a try.
It is similar to screen but with added features like a vertical split without any unofficial patches, etc. Also the default look is better IMO.

I use it for instance to run `irssi`, `rtorrent` etc so that I dont have to quit them when dropping back to console from X or switching to another Window Manager. Also, when used from the console (no X running), tmux (like screen) lets you use multiple terminal instances in a single vt/tty.

Hence for your particular scenario, install `tmux` in the server, ssh, run tmux and then the app. When you want to reboot your local PC, detach the tmux session with `C-b d` (default keybinding for tmux) and then reboot. Once you are up again, ssh and attach to the session with `tmux attach -d`

Answer (score 1):

Try *screen* - it's the perfect tool for this kind of things. You can detach your current session and re-attach later from a different terminal etc.